# ctrl+shift+E shortcut in vscode is hijacked by an extension and I don't know which

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I have some extensions installed in vscode and when i try to use the explorer shortcut it closes the whole window and I don't know which extension is causing that. I tried disabling all of them and when I try the shortcut nothing happens. I cannot figure out how to go about this. Any help is greatly appreciated.
ps: I use vscode version 1.50.1 on windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look in the full list of Vscode shortcuts, accessible in `File → Preferences → Keyboard shortcuts`